# How to rebase off master with github client?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase

I'm used to a workflow on the command line that doesn't seem to be able to translate to the GitHub client GUI.

I branch off master, do some work, other people do work, other people merge their work, I git pull my master branch, I rebase my branch off new master, then I PR and merge my branch.

https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

I just am not seeing how I can rebase off an updated master with GitHub GUI?  I REALLY like to keep all my commits for a particular PR and branch grouped together for a log that looks like:

```
merge my stuff
my commit 3
my commit 2
my commit 1
merge dev-a's stuff
dev-a commit 3
dev-a commit 2
dev-a commit 1
...
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but what prevents you from doing rebase in command line and doing other staff in GitHub client?

Comment: Trying to teach non git users who only want to use GUI.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, it is not possible to do anything more than some of the basic git command in Github GUI. A much better alternative would be to use SourceTree which supports some advanced level of git commands via the GUI